# SpreadsheetApp was working now it's not (from last night to this morning nothing has changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My code was worked last night, nothing has changed now it will not work.  Issues with the SpreadsheetApp, I found there were issues in Feb and March - where old code worked and now it doesn't. I have looked at the new V8 engine.
I have looked in the Trouble Shoot V8, my code matches.  I have enabled and disabled V8 engine.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Now this is saying:

> Type error: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 31, file "Code")

```
ss.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(eventTitle);
ss.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(sd);
```

My code

```
function myFunction()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   //ss.close();

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("...@group.calendar.google.com");
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date ("5/15/2020 12:00 AM"), new Date 
         ("5/30/20 11:59 PM"));
  var header = [["Student Meeting","Event Start", "Event 
      End","Location","Guest Email"]];

 for(var i = 0; i<events.length; i++)
  {
    var row = i+2;

    var eventTitle = events[i].getTitle();
    var sd = events[i].getStartTime();
    var ed = events[i].getEndTime();
    var location = events[i].getLocation();
    var guestsEmail = events[i].getGuestList();

    var guest = '';
    var guest1 = '';

    for(var j = 0; j < guestsEmail.length; j++)
    {

      guest = guest + guestsEmail[j].getEmail()+ '\n';
      guest1 = guest1 + " Status: " + guestsEmail[j].getGuestStatus()+'\n';
     }

    ss.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(eventTitle);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(sd);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 2).setNumberFormat("MM/DD/YY hh:mm");
    ss.getRange(i+2, 3).setValue(ed);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 3).setNumberFormat("hh:mm");
    ss.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(location);
    ss.getRange(i+2, 5).setValue(guest);


  }
    ss.sort(2);
    ss.insertRowBefore(1);
    var range = ss.getRange(1,1,1,5);
    range.setValues(header);


}
```

[image: see code work]

[image]

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for troubleshooting.

Comment: How is the function called?

Comment: I just run it.  So every time I need to run it I press run to that sheet and it clears it and then reloads. The close -  I took out and re-added for this paste it was clear. Does that answer your question? I only need it to work for 7 days.

Comment: How are you running it? Button on sheet? or from tools> script editor>"Run" button? or time triggers?

Comment: tools> script editor>"Run"

Comment: If you attempt to run using `tools> script editor>"Run"`, then `Type error: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 31, file "Code")`  shows up? screenshot of code please

Comment: It is fixed, it was organization block, Thank you so much for trying to help me, I really appreciate it.